# how to change the booting mode of raspberry pi?

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi

i am working on raspberry pi.  i want to boot raspberry in text mode and it will ask for login. and i want to change booting mode  from GUI to text mode, from text mode to GUI mode through command.

Comment: IMHO this is off-topic here, probably better ask on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the raspi-config script on github, especially the do_boot_behaviour function --> https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config

This function in combination with enable_boot_to_scratch and disable_boot_to_scratch does exactly what you are looking for.